# Order Results of search query mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query for a search function. I have in my data 3 different account types that I need to show in a specific order. For that I used `ORDER BY FIELD(profiltype,2,1,3)`. That works great and with no problems, however within these results I also need to order the different columns in a priority like:

```
1. name2
2. a_z_feld1
etc.
```

However this is not working with the query I have below. It should keep the order of Profile types but within this order also have a priority of the columns.

```
SELECT * FROM main_users 
WHERE ((name2 LIKE %s) 
OR (a_z_feld1 LIKE %s) 
OR (a_z_feld2 LIKE %s) 
OR (a_z_feld3 LIKE %s) 
OR (city LIKE %s) 
OR (content_stellenvor LIKE %s) 
OR (main_content LIKE %s)) 
AND levelmember <> 1 
ORDER BY FIELD(profiltype,2,1,3) ASC, 
a_z_feld1 ASC, a_z_feld2 ASC, a_z_feld3 ASC
```

Comment: try to indent your query so so we can read it

Comment: Provide the mysql query alone to be more readable.

Comment: priority of WHICH columns? Your code is making my eyes bleed.

Comment: i need to split my results first into 3 groups which I am doing with ORDER BY FIELD(profiltype,2,1,3) and after that I need order by priority. Meaning if I have first all results with profiletype 2 then in these results I need to show first the once with a matching value in column "name2" after that with a matching column "a_z_feld1" etc...

Comment: Your code looks good. Can you provide some simplified results you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you need to include `name` in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(profiltype,2,1,3) ASC, name2, a_z_feld1 ASC, a_z_feld2 ASC, a_z_feld3 ASC
```

Comment: yes...but that does not work either. I just forgot to take it. A simple solution would be to just do:

ORDER BY profiltype = 2 DESC, profiltype = 1 DESC, profiltype = 3 DESC, name2 LIKE %s DESC, a_z_feld1 LIKE %s DESC, a_z_feld2 LIKE %s DESC, a_z_feld3 LIKE %s DESC, main_content LIKE %s DESC, content_stellenvor LIKE %s DESC

but that is not a good query